# What are those tutorial shells?

Tags: shell, terminal

What are the code tutorial shells called that are used on various websites such as codecademy, codeschool, mongo db, try ruby etc.

Is there a service for building and maintaining these things? Or is it something you build yourself?

I found [ShellInABox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/downloads/list) but it doesn't seem exactly like the only one people are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are colloquially known as "web REPLs" (a [term meaning "Read/Eval/Print Loop"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)).

They can be distinguished by unrestricted ones used for debugging by describing them as "sandboxed". There is not a single, universal toolkit used to build these, though you may find [repl.it](http://repl.it/) (which uses a number of interpreters compiled to javascript to run client-side REPLs for numerous languages) interesting.

Comment: According to that page the 2 authors of repl.it work for CodeSchool and Google. If you've ever tried a CodeSchool course, you'll know these things work great. And the code is right here https://github.com/replit/repl.it (sweet)